# jQuery Field Change Submit not working

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input, submit

I have the below form that i want to remove the submit button from (or hide it).

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="3" size="1" maxlength="2" />
<input name="adjustBtn" type="submit" value="change" />
<input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="1" />
</form>
```

In a jQuery file called test.js that i have included in the page i have the bellow that should submit the form when the input field "quantity" has changed, but it does not, i cannot get it to work and i have tried all sorts of form submit functions from other posts on SO. One person even said that if the submit button had a name of submit it would not work but i do not have that.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#quantity').change(function(){
       //$(this).closest("form").submit(); <-- commented out as not working either.
       //$(this).closest('form')[0].submit(); <-- commented out as not working either.
       $('#adjustBtn').submit();
    });

} );
```

Anyone have any idea why it wont submit the form? I have tested in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to submit the `form` instead of the `button`:

```
$("#adjustBtn").closest("form").submit();
```

Also, you didn't give an `id` to your `adjustBtn`, thus `$("#adjustBtn")` won't work;

```
<input id="adjustBtn" name="adjustBtn" type="submit" value="change" />
```

The same thing happens with `#quantity`, that's why the `change` handler doesn't get fired, you need to also add the `id`:

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" value="3" size="1" maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: i just changed this and still nothing, to make it more interesting i added `console.log("Data Changed! Submit!!!!");` after the .change line and when i change the input field i get nothing in the console. Makes me think its not even registering.

Comment: @medoix: Oh I see, you missed the `id` attribute on your inputs. `$("#id")` selects by `id`, not by `name`. Please see my updated anser.

Comment: sigh.. thanks haha cannot believe it was as simple as using ID instead of the Name field.

Comment: would this work with multiple lines of items? i.e multiple forms with the same input field with id of "quantity"?

Comment: @medoix: An `id` must be unique across the page. It should work, but it's not very *correct*. An alternative is to select by name, i.e., instead of `$("#quantity")`, use `$("[name='quantity']")`, though the selector will be slighly slower.

Comment: I basically have a foreach loop in PHP outputting multiple forms and the content depending on what is stored in $_SESSION, each adjustBtn has a number at the end adjustBtn1 etc depending on the product id. Is there a way to control this through jquery as it does not know what the number for the button is? So far what i currently have only works for the first item in the list and none of the bellow :(

Comment: @medoix: There is, yes, you can use `$("[id^=adjustBtn"])`, for example. It will select all elements whose id *starts with* adjustBtn, including adjustBtn1, adjustBtn2, etc. Then, you could extract the number from the `id`.

Comment: Would you be able to show an example? I get the selecting all id fields but not the how to use the id to determine which form to submit. Or should i open another question?

Comment: Sure, you could use, for example `this.id.match(/(\d+)/)[1]` to extract the `id` number, within the `change` event handler. Also, yes, please do open another question if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" id="autoSubmit">
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="3" size="1" maxlength="2" />
<input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="1" />
</form>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#quantity').change(function(){
       $('#autoSubmit').submit();
    });

} );
```